# builtins.TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing a GUI for an app.

```
def answer():
    showerror("Answer", "Sorry, no answer available")

def callback():
    if askyesno('Verify', 'Really quit?'):
        showwarning('Yes', 'Not yet implemented')
    else:
        showinfo('No', 'Quit has been cancelled')

button(text='Quit', command=callback).pack(fill=X)
button(text='Answer', command=answer).pack(fill=X)
```

I have this error below.

```
builtins.TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable
```

Can anyone kindly help me to point out what is the cause of this mistake and how to correct it?

Comment: There's not enough code to diagnose the problem. The error mentions `Button` but nowhere in the code do you have anything named `Button`. Please read and follow the advice to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I understand `Button` is an in-built widget available from `Tkinter`. :) However, you have to put the complete code to fix the exact problem. Below is my anticipation:

Check `button` variable initialization if you have intended to do so. The call which you made with it is the actual problem. You can fix like this:

```
    from tkinter import *
    win=tkinter.Toplevel()
    frame=tkinter.Frame(master=win).grid(row=1,column=1)
    #include your piece of method definitions here
    CBbutton = tkinter.Button(master=frame, text='Quit', command=callback)
    Ansbutton = tkinter.Button(master=frame, text='answer', command=answer)
    #Below code calls the 'button' object. So, you see, I havent passed any parameters within it, and so it is not callable that way.
    CBbutton.pack(fill='x')
    Ansbutton.pack(fill='x')
```